# Insert data into a Temporary Table from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure called Sp_Ejecucion inside it create a temporary table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE #CambioResult (FOL INT IDENTITY, RESULT INT)
```

and after that command to run another Sp as follows

```
BEGIN TRAN T1
DECLARE @vnCambiaRollTurnoResult    INT = 0,
        @vnReacomodoMarcajesResult  INT = 0,
        @Result                     INT = 0

BEGIN TRY
    exec nsp_Exec                   @nClaEmp        = @pnClaEmpresa, 
                                    @nClaTrab       = @pnClaTrab, 
                                    
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    GOTO RETURN_ERROR
END CATCH
```

And the inside of the second stored I want to insert data to the table created in the first stored, How can I do it? what I have intended is the following:

```
INSERT INTO OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CambioResult')
select @Error
```

pero marca error en esta parte **OBJECT_ID**

Comment: A temporary table only persists for the duration of the scope it was created in. If you create a temporary table inside a procedure it will therefore be implicitly dropped once the procedure completes. If you want to pass data between procedures then one method would be to have the first pass the data as a table type parameter to the second.

Comment: If you're calling a procedure from within the first procedure where you create the temp table, the table will be visible in the nested procedure - you just insert into it `insert into #CambioResult(Result) select @error`

Comment: Or you could create the table outside of both stored procedures, then it will only be dropped after your outer procedure or batch finishes

Answer (score 0):

As you are inserting within the nested procedure, you will be able to reference the parent procedure temporary table `#CambioResult` inside nested procedure.

You have to change your INSERT statement in the nested procedure: `nsp_Exec` as given below:

```sql
INSERT INTO #CambioResult
SELECT ....
```

About Temporary table scope, [reference msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables)

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope,
> unless explicitly dropped by using DROP TABLE:
>
> - A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be
>   referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored
>   procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by
>   the process that called the stored procedure that created the table